# How to scroll two components with one's vertical scroll bar only

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on displaying lines numbers for a richTextBox on C#, I tried many components but non of them worked with me, so I'm working on my own one.

I implemented that using the richTextBox + ListBox.

But, I'm having a problem when scrolling the richtextbox,the ListBox wont scroll, also I need not the vScrollBar of the List box to appear during scroll how can I accomplish this?

I mean scrolling both (richTextBox+listBox) when scrolling the richTextBox only, any suggestions?

Comment: please don't repeat tags (like "C#") in the title. Leave them in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make this reliable.  RichTextBox allows continuous scrolling where only a portion of a line is in view.  ListBox does not.  The line numbers will not line up with the lines most of the time.

Use a real text editor, like ScintillaNET.  It supports showing line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener on an OnScroll* event and update the other control as one of them is scrolled.